# Why isn't GKE scaling down cluster nodes even though I only have one pod?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I know there are some existing questions out there, they usually refer to this https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#i-have-a-couple-of-nodes-with-low-utilization-but-they-are-not-scaled-down-why

But Im still having trouble debugging. I only have 1 pod running on my cluster so I don't see why it wouldn't scale to 1 node. How can I debug this further?

Heres some info:

```
kubectl get nodes
NAME                                                STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-4k84   Ready    <none>   4h14m   v1.14.10-gke.27
gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-6wfs   Ready    <none>   16d     v1.14.10-gke.27
gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-74lm   Ready    <none>   4h13m   v1.14.10-gke.27
gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-m223   Ready    <none>   4h13m   v1.14.10-gke.27
gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-srlg   Ready    <none>   66d     v1.14.10-gke.27
```

```
kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
qua-gke-foobar1234-5959446675-njzh4   1/1     Running   0          14m
```

```
nodePools:
- autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    maxNodeCount: 10
    minNodeCount: 1
  config:
    diskSizeGb: 100
    diskType: pd-standard
    imageType: COS
    machineType: n1-highcpu-32
    metadata:
      disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
    serviceAccount: default
    shieldedInstanceConfig:
      enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
  initialNodeCount: 1
  instanceGroupUrls:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/fooooobbbarrr-dev/zones/us-central1-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-qua-gke-foobar1234-default-pool-6302174e-grp
  locations:
  - us-central1-a
  management:
    autoRepair: true
    autoUpgrade: true
  name: default-pool
  podIpv4CidrSize: 24
  selfLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/ffoooobarrrr-dev/locations/us-central1/clusters/qua-gke-foobar1234/nodePools/default-pool
  status: RUNNING
  version: 1.14.10-gke.27
```

```
kubectl describe horizontalpodautoscaler
Name:               qua-gke-foobar1234
Namespace:          default
Labels:             <none>
Annotations:        autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/conditions:
                      [{"type":"AbleToScale","status":"True","lastTransitionTime":"2020-03-17T19:59:19Z","reason":"ReadyForNewScale","message":"recommended size...
                    autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/current-metrics:
                      [{"type":"External","external":{"metricName":"pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages","metricSelector":{"matchLabels"...
                    autoscaling.alpha.kubernetes.io/metrics:
                      [{"type":"External","external":{"metricName":"pubsub.googleapis.com|subscription|num_undelivered_messages","metricSelector":{"matchLabels"...
                    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                      {"apiVersion":"autoscaling/v2beta1","kind":"HorizontalPodAutoscaler","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"qua-gke-foobar1234","namespace":...
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 17 Mar 2020 12:59:03 -0700
Reference:          Deployment/qua-gke-foobar1234
Min replicas:       1
Max replicas:       10
Deployment pods:    1 current / 1 desired
Events:             <none>
```

Comment: Check `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`

Comment: HPA is for pod autoscaling, not node. Do you have node autoscaler enabled. What's the minimum number of nodes set to scale down?

Comment: You should check the logs to see what decision the autoscaler is making https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler-visibility

Comment: Checks the pods in all workspace and provide more details in your question

Comment: @coderanger Ahh I see https://gist.github.com/danielyaa5/0779e29ca72869e7b290ae33c6817157 so probably some of these are preventing nodes from shutting down

Comment: In the readme though it only specifies how to create a pdb for one of the pods but what about all the others?

Comment: Can I set the min available on all these system pods to 1 or do I need to keep some of them with multiple?

Comment: I ran these pdbs but I dont see anychanges to nodes or pods https://gist.github.com/danielyaa5/e72ed93aeb3929c66c35afd5eb0395c3

Answer (score 2):

`HorizontalPodAutoscaler` will increase or decrease the number of **pods**, not nodes. It doesn't have anything to do with the node scaling.

Node scaling is handled by the cloud provider, in your case, by Google Cloud Platform.

You should check if you have node autoscaler enabled or not from the GCP console.

You should follow these steps: 
1. Go to the the [Kubernetes clusters screen](https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes/list) on GCP console
2. Click on your cluster
3. From the bottom, click on the node pool you want to enable autoscaling for
4. Click "edit"
5. Enable autoscaling, define minimum and maximum number of nodes, and save. See the screenshot:

[image: Enable node autoscaling]

Alternatively, via the `gcloud` CLI, as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-autoscaler#enabling_autoscaling_for_an_existing_node_pool):

```
gcloud container clusters update cluster-name --enable-autoscaling \
    --min-nodes 1 --max-nodes 10 --zone compute-zone --node-pool default-pool
```

Comment: My cluster is set up for autoscaling already, ```nodePools:
- autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    maxNodeCount: 10
    minNodeCount: 1``` that part of my post is from `gcloud container clusters describe cluster-name`

Comment: The reason I posted my horizontal scaling object is because in my case each pod requires it's own node so when a new pod is added by horizontal scaling it needs to request a new node from gcloud

Answer (score 1):

So the original problem with my debugging attempt was that I ran `kubectl get pods` and not `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` so I couldnt see the pods running on the system. Then I add PDBs on all the system pods.

```
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-event --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=event-exporter --max-unavailable 1 &&
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-fluentd-scaler --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=fluentd-gcp-scaler --max-unavailable 1 &&
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-heapster --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=heapster --max-unavailable 1 &&
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-dns --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns --max-unavailable 1 &&
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-dnsauto --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=kube-dns-autoscaler --max-unavailable 1 &&
kubectl create poddisruptionbudget pdb-glbc --namespace=kube-system --selector k8s-app=glbc --max-unavailable 1
```

I then was starting to get these errors on some of the pdb event logs. `controllermanager  Failed to calculate the number of expected pods: found no controllers for pod`, I saw these in the pdb evens when I ran `kubectl describe pdb --all-namespaces`. I dont know why these were occuring but I removed those pdbs. Then everything started working!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the cause was the lack of PDBs for workloads running in **kube-system** NS. You can check the "Autoscaler Logs" tab.

[image]

If you don't configure PDBs, cluster autoscaler won't remove surplus GKE nodes. https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-types-of-pods-can-prevent-ca-from-removing-a-node

There is an interesting discussion about whether there should be some default behaviour or PDB. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/35318